# CoordinatorLayout not working properly when content inside NestedScrollView doesn't fill entire screen

Tags: android, appbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

When there is less data inside the nested scrollview then the view gets stuck to the footer. When it has enough content to show it works as expected. I have a CoordinatorLayout at root which has AppBarLayout and NestedScrollView as child. AppBarLayout has a collapsingToolbarLayout and NestedScrollView has a LinearLayout.

**If content inside NestedScrollView is not enough and it can't fill the screen it gets stuck to the footer and I have to scroll in this tiny area to scroll up the appbar**. I hope I'm making some sense.

Here is my layout file

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <!-- Your scrolling content -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info"
                android:text="@string/hello_world"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/expanded_toolbar_title_margin_start"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profilePic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/avatar_empty"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

There is something silly I'm doing or there is some xml attribute to help with this. Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should update the library version you're using, your problem is fixed check out this link. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175243

Comment: @ErikJhordanReyCaffrey thanks, upgrading worked.